# Android Studio, issue while creating a google map apps

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-studio-3.0

I am fairly new to Android development, trying to create a google map app by following an online course. As suggested in the course I have below versions
Android Studio Version 3.0.1.
Compile S d k version API30.
Build tools version 30.0.0.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awBy4.png)

And this is an error coming up.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrC4P.png)

help me out, please

Comment: please check official documentation ... your course is outdated

Comment: Is there way without changing Android studio version (i,e 3.0.1) and getting this done ?? because my online course require me to use this particular version ..

Comment: someone please help me